# RC Excel International Alternative

Tags: excel

I have a named range in Excel which is something like:

```
INDIRECT("RC[-2]";0)
```

I goes two columns to the left and gets whats there. But he thing is that this is not International, and it is not working for other languages.

What would be the international version to do this?

Comment: Which languages cause problem? What is the problem exactly? What error message does Excel write in cell? If you provide this information it would help us to solve your problem, believe me.

Comment: You might also wanna look into `OFFSET` function - it uses numbers as parameters thus it's not locale-dependent.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry for not sharing on time.

```
=OFFSET(INDIRECT(ADDRESS(ROW(), COLUMN())),0,-2)
```

Comment: I have to wait 2 days for that.